# Wifi problems on Ubuntu dual boot windows10; Tried to fix, now it doesn't work on windows 10 or Ubuntu

Tags: networking, dual-boot, drivers, wireless

I am not sure where to post this, but since it originated as an Ubuntu problem I will try here.

First of all I am having this problem on my laptop, ASUS K501UB-DM016T, which has a "intel dual band wireless-ac 7265" wireless card.

So here is what has been going on:

I installed Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS as dual boot with Windows 10, and I enabled WiFi and logged on to my network, and everything worked!

But then after a reboot or something it stopped working. Whenever I press enable WiFi it instantly turns off. So I started troubleshooting and after several hours over a couple of days I wasn't able to solve the issue, and then I went to go use Windows 10, the WiFi no longer worked. So sadly I cannot remember what exactly I did during the troubleshooting, and now I have a much greater problem than what I started with.

On Windows 10 it does not instantly disable when I enable WiFi, it drops the connection to the network as soon as it connects.

Here is a log of some information that might be useful: 
https://pastebin.com/HCUGm9Tu

I have tried reinstalling the drivers for my wireless card. I also tried to reset all bios settings to default, since I had been tinkering with them for other reasons.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe a hardware issue?

Comment: Maybe, but how could I make sure?

Comment: I think it's hardware-related because it has similar behaviour on both OSes. There's no file or driver shared by Win and Ubuntu. You can give a try with a live usb and see what happen. Generally Intel 7265 cards are well supported by the latest Linux kernels. If the card is ok you shouldn't have any problem to connect with a live OS.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the BIOS to defaults?  Is there a switch on it to enable/disable the wireless

Comment: I have reset BIOS, and there is no switch.

Comment: There *is* a switch - FN+F2 - that activates "airplane mode". Please check that before anything else. And no, it has nothing to do with Ubuntu, no matter what perspective you look at it.

Comment: I have checked that, and it is not in airplane mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was actually 2 separate issues. Today an Ubuntu update dropped, and now my WiFi works just fine. As for Windows 10 it appears only not to work on my home network ( No other devices are experiencing this ), this I will look into separately, since it is not related to Ubuntu.